# get selected value from drop down

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vb.net

I want to change the zip code according to drop down list for example if i select Canada from drop down list name `"ddlselcountry"` and Canada is at 40th place in drop down, for that only zip code should change (what is the condition i should put in for 'if condition') and for other country it should go to else condition.

I have tried this in upper example but i am not going inside if condition,It is generating error.

```
if ($("#ddlselcountry")[0].selectedindex == "40"){
  var zipCodePattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[ ]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$/;
  return zipCodePattern.test(zipcode);
}
```

Comment: use `$('#ddlselcountry).val()` to check `selected value` of the dropdown

Comment: Which error does it produce?

Answer (score 0):

It is `selectedIndex` not `selectedindex`. It is case sensitive.

```
$("#ddlselcountry")[0].selectedIndex
```

Instead of this you can use

```
$("#ddlselcountry").val() == 'value of canada';
```

Comment: still not able to get result.

Answer (score 0):

Please change selectedindex to selectedIndex 
$("#ddlselcountry").selectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

U can try this

```
if ($("#ddlselcountry").selectedIndex == "40"){
  var zipCodePattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[ ]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$/;
  return zipCodePattern.test(zipcode);
}
```